# How to localize a simple HTML website page in my case?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am **NOT** developing any web service application which contain *client* side and backend *server* side (like java EE application or Ruby on Rails).

Instead, I am simply developing a HTML **website page**, on this page, there are two flag images(USA and China) which is used as a language selection of the page for users.

I am wondering, for this single web page development (without any backend system), is there any efficient way to implement the **page localization**(that's display the page in different language) based on the flag selection from user?

Comment: Yes. Make two pages, one in English and one in Chinese. Link the US flag to the English version and the Chinese flag to the Chinese version.

Comment: No, I don't think it's possible. You'd have to have some kind of javascript in order to switch between the two languages.

Comment: @Juhana he wants to make one single website page

Comment: not sure I understand the question. Do you want a tool that automatically translates the page?

Answer (score 33):

You can use the standard HTML `lang` attribute:

```
<span lang="en">Scale</span><span lang="de">Maßstab</span>
```

And then you can hide and show the matching elements:

```
function select_language(language) {
    $("[lang]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("lang") == language)
            $(this).show();
        else
            $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

I use a simple selection:

```
<select onchange="select_language(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
  <option value="en" selected>English</option>
  <option value="de">Deutsch</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 14):

Nowadays I would do it without jQuery. First I would hide all nodes with a `lang` attribute and show only the default language. This can be done in CSS:

```
[lang] {
  display: none;
}
[lang=en] {
  display: unset;
}
```

Without JavaScript enabled the document is not localized but at least readable in the default language.

Next I would use some JavaScript to show the correct language, if it is in the list of supported languages.

```
function localize (language)
{
  if (['de'].includes(language)) {
    let lang = ':lang(' + language + ')';
    let hide = '[lang]:not(' + lang + ')';
    document.querySelectorAll(hide).forEach(function (node) {
      node.style.display = 'none';
    });
    let show = '[lang]' + lang;
    document.querySelectorAll(show).forEach(function (node) {
      node.style.display = 'unset';
    });
  }
}
```

You can either use a select box or the browser language.

```
localize(window.navigator.language);
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way around this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Localise</title>
</head>

<body>  
    <a href="#china" onclick="showthis('contentchina')">China flag</a>|
    <a href="#usa" onclick="showthis('contentusa')">USA flag</a>

    <div id="contentchina" style="display:none">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
    </div>

    <div id="contentusa" style="display:none">
        Duis aute irure dolor...
    </div>

    <script>
    function showthis(nation) {
        document.getElementById(nation).style.display = "block";
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'd probably want a complimentary `hideThis()` (or toggle) function so that you don't end up displaying both at once - but otherwise yeah, a nice simple solution.

Comment: Using the `id` for localization limits the use to exactly one element, because the `id` tag must me unique. This prevents mixing localized and non localized content or it requires the duplication of content, which does not need any localization. So it might be better to use the `class` tag.

Comment: Can you tell me how to hide one language when another one is selected ?

Answer (score 2):

Your webpage needs to understand what encoding it should be using when rendering Chinese characters:

```
 <! -- NOTICE THE "charset=UTF-8" !!!! -->
<head>    
    <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type"/>
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use JavaScript to read the user language and show the right flag/content:

HTML:

```
<img id="myFlag" src="flag_default.png"/>
```

and some jQuery (since you tagged your question with jQuery):

```
var supportedLangs = ['de', 'en', 'cn'];
var userLang = navigator.language;

if($.inArray(userLang, supportedLangs) >= 0){
    $('myFlag').attr('src', 'flag_' + userLang + '.png');
}
```

[hjsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/timbuethe/3sjwc/)

Comment: I am building an offline multi-page mobile application and I am trying to make it so that the application can detect only certain '<h1>'s or tags and translate them to the locale language the users phone is set to, while leaving other '<h1>' or tags in the source language, is there a way/method to make this work for that? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38416738/locale-language-detection-and-translation?noredirect=1#comment64244549_38416738).

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking into a template engine for this problem.  To me it's not *exactly* a `backend` but more of a grey area. Something like [**Moustache**](http://mustache.github.com/) OR [**smarty**](http://www.smarty.net/) would be perfect for you.

Simply put, i agree with the other posters that this is not reasonable to achieve on the client side.

Comment: i think same, but somehow since my UI is different project, i look for client side, looking at the answer they seem not to be enterprise at all, and require lot of writing and the code become messy after a short time. also these answers does not supports fallbacks. the Moustache can be good, but i didn't get even a bit of it on first sight, so i think i just use cshtml instead of plain HTML, sure that will have overheat on server if request goes high, instead of just transfer, it also require server side processing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.  Here is one way

Structure you HTML like this in your folders

```
/root
  /Chinese
  /English-American
  index.html
```

The root folder would contain your page with the language selection and the Chinese and English-American will contain your language specific pages.

Now on index.html simply direct the user to the correct language folder and all links will reference the correct language folder

Answer (score 0):

If you want your page to be search engine friendly, you have to put both static version in the HTML. You can put them into two `div` and when user clicks on a flag you shows the correct `div`.

You can also use a template like [Mustache](https://github.com/janl/mustache.js) to render content with JavaScript. Then you can write your non-localized content as a template and make localized content as variables.

Answer (score 0):

Generally JS generating the code for you is not good.
But, I did one POC for the same using **underscore.js**. The framework is having an "_template" function that helps us to replace all the keys in the HTML file. The function accepts the key value pair in JSON format.

Based on the language selected, load the corresponding JSON file and then pass it on to the _template function. This will replace all the keys.

Comment: It always a good practice to keep the JS minimum. This will help to increase the performance of a sit. Hell lot of code is required for manipulating the DOM elements for localization.

Comment: More or less lines JS code is arbitrary. It all depends on how expensive your code is when it comes to performance. Sane, concise JS code can be quite performant, or at least performant enough that the user doesn't notice any lag. Rendering templates with underscore probably won't be a bottleneck, and if it is, you could always pre-render the templates and serve them statically for each language you offer.

Answer (score -1):

Easy answer: No, using a backend is the easiest and best way to accomplish this.  Backend code is designed for dynamic content, which is what you want.

Hard answer: This is a way to do this without dividing up your pages into two directories.  The problem is that you're going to have to use Javascript to generate your page content, and that's generally a *bad idea*.  But you could use a javascript MVC library, plus ajax calls to content folders that pull in the text (you'd still have to have two directories for English and Chinese, but they would only contain content, not HTML).  The thing is, there's multiple potential problems with this method that it's only worth using if you **know** your users will have a modern browser with javascript enabled.