# Hide div id="en" if value=$en

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, hide, html

Can anyone help me with the languages ​​on my page. I have a menu from which I choose language - English, Croatian or German.
I give you the code of the file to change languages

```
    <?php
    class home_header_language
    {   
        protected   $_DBconn;
        protected   $_front_template;
        protected   $_view;
        public function __construct($view) 
        {
            $this->_front_template = Zend_Registry::get('front_template'); 
            $this->_view =  $view;

        }
        public function truncate($phrase,$start_words, $max_words)
        {
           $phrase_array = explode(' ',$phrase);
           if(count($phrase_array) > $max_words && $max_words > 0)
              $phrase = implode(' ',array_slice($phrase_array, $start_words, $max_words)).'...';  
           return $phrase;
        }

        public function class_body()
        {   
            $translator = Zend_Registry::get('translator'); 
            $globalForm = new Settings_Form_GlobalSettingsForm();   
            $lang_arr = $globalForm->default_language->getMultiOptions();   
            if(Eicra_Global_Variable::getSession()->sess_lang)
            {
                $default_lang_code = Eicra_Global_Variable::getSession()->sess_lang;    
                $default_lang_name =    $globalForm->default_language->getMultiOption($default_lang_code);
                $default_lang_code_arr = explode('_', $default_lang_code);
                $default_territory_code = $default_lang_code_arr[1];
            }
            else
            {
                $global_conf = Zend_Registry::get('global_conf');
                $default_lang_code = $global_conf['default_language'];
                $default_lang_name = $globalForm->default_language->getMultiOption($default_lang_code);
                $default_lang_code_arr = explode('_', $default_lang_code);
                $default_territory_code = $default_lang_code_arr[1];
            }           
            $default_site_lang_arr  =   Zend_Locale_Data::getList($default_lang_code, 'language');
            $default_site_lang = $default_site_lang_arr[$default_lang_code_arr[0]];

            $default_site_territory_arr =   Zend_Locale_Data::getList($default_lang_code, 'territory');
            $default_site_territory = $default_site_territory_arr[$default_territory_code]; 
            $tab_base_link = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRequest()->getRequestUri();   
        ?>

            <script type="text/javascript">     
            $(document).ready(function() { //on DOM ready
                    $("a.change_lang").click(function() {   
                        var self = this;
                        var lang = $(self).attr('rel');

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo $this->_view->url( array('module' => 'Settings','controller' => 'language', 'action'     => 'update' ), 'adminrout',    true) ?>",
                                type: 'POST',
                                data: { lang_name : lang },
                                beforeSend: function(){                             
                                    $(self).children("span:nth-child(1)").children("img:nth-child(1)").attr('src','data/adminImages/commonImages/flag_loader.gif'); 
                                    $(self).children("span:nth-child(1)").children("img:nth-child(1)").attr('height','15');                 
                                 },
                                success: function(response)
                                {   
                                    //alert(response);                                          
                                    var json_arr = eval("("+response+")");  
                                    var url = '<?php echo $tab_base_link; ?>';
                                    var baseUrl = '<?php echo $this->_view->baseUrl(); ?>';
                                    var ckUrl = 'Administrator/login/auth';
                                    var match_res = url.match(/Administrator\/login\/auth/g);
                                    var tmp = false;
                                    for (i in match_res) 
                                    {
                                        if(match_res[i] == ckUrl){ tmp = true;  }
                                      //alert(i + ' : ' + match_res[i]);
                                    }
                                    if(tmp == true)
                                    {
                                        var rightUrl = baseUrl+'/Administrator';
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        var rightUrl = url;
                                    }               

                                    if(json_arr.status == 'ok')
                                    {
                                        document.location.href=rightUrl;                                                    
                                    }                       
                                }
                          });
                    });
                });

            </script>

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(".dropdown img.flag").addClass(""); //flagvisibility

                $(".dropdown dt a").click(function() {
                    $(".dropdown dd ul").toggle();
                });

                $(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
                    var text = $(this).html();
                    $(".dropdown dt a span").html(text);
                    $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                    $("#result").html("Selected value is: " + getSelectedValue("sample"));
                });

                function getSelectedValue(id) {
                    return $("#" + id).find("dt a span.value").html();
                }

                $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
                    var $clicked = $(e.target);
                    if (! $clicked.parents().hasClass("dropdown"))
                        $(".dropdown dd ul").hide();
                });


                $("#flagSwitcher").click(function() {
                    $(".dropdown img.flag").toggleClass("flagvisibility");
                });
            });
            </script>


<dl id="sample" class="dropdown" style="margin:0; padding:0;">
                <dt><a href="javascript:void(0);"><span><?php echo $default_site_lang.' - '.$default_site_territory; ?><span class="flag"><img src="data/adminImages/flagsImage/<?php echo $default_territory_code; ?>.gif" border="0" title="<?php echo $default_lang_name; ?>" /></span></span></a></dt>
<dd>
<ul>
<?php
if($lang_arr)
{
foreach($lang_arr as $lang_arr_key => $lang_arr_value)
{
$key_arr = explode('_', $lang_arr_key);
$iso_code = $key_arr[0];
$territory_code = $key_arr[1];
$localeData = Zend_Locale_Data::getList($lang_arr_key, 'layout');
$site_direction = $localeData['characters'];
$site_direction_symbol = ($site_direction == 'right-to-left') ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
$site_lang_arr  =   Zend_Locale_Data::getList($lang_arr_key, 'language');
$site_lang = $site_lang_arr[$iso_code];
$site_territory_arr =   Zend_Locale_Data::getList($lang_arr_key, 'territory');
$site_territory = $site_territory_arr[$territory_code];
?>

<li><a class="change_lang" rel="<?php echo $lang_arr_key.':'.$site_direction_symbol; ?>" href="javascript:void(0);"><?php echo $site_lang.' - '.$site_territory; ?><span class="flag"><img src="data/adminImages/flagsImage/<?php echo $territory_code; ?>.gif" border="0" title="<?php echo $lang_arr_value; ?>" /></span></a></li>

<?php
}
}
?>
</ul>
</dd>
</dl>
    <?php
        }
    }

    try
    {
        $home_header_language_class = new home_header_language($this);
        $home_header_language_class->class_body();
    }
    catch(Exception $e)
    {
        echo 'You have to create menu first.';
    }
    ?>
```

In many places in the page I have this sample:

```
<div id="en">English text</div>
<div id="hr">Hrvatski text</div>
<div id="de">German text</div>
```

How can I hide div's with id=hr and id=de if I choice English language.

Thanks for help.

Comment: See [**this**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16497937/991954) answer (use standart `lang` html tag)

Answer (score 2):

You are over complicating things. You can simply achieve the desired results by applying a class to all the language divs.

Lets add a class "lang" to the language divs. The updated html markup would be

```
<div id="en" class="lang">English text</div>
<div id="hr" class="lang">Hrvatski text</div>
<div id="de" class="lang">German text</div>
```

For example if we wanted to show the English language, we have to hide all and show this English one

The sample code is like below:

```
 // To hide all languages
 $(".lang").hide();

 // To show the desired one
 $("#en").show();
```

**NOTE:**

*You have to show the selected div dynamically using the above code, I have shown the English one for demo purpose. All you have to do is use your selection logic and follow the same pattern to hide and show*

[Simple Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y2AXk/)

Comment: What if selected language is German or Hrvatski? How code is detect  which is selected language on page load.

Comment: You can to specify via php by adding a class 'selected'

Comment: @Karolev you can use jQuery change event to detect when the selection changes and then follow my logic, first hide all elements and then show the selected one. More info about 'change' event on http://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: I'm not very good with a jQuery. I would be grateful if you give me an example how to do this. Thanks in advance!