# How to add a button to convert language

Tags: html

Hey I was wondering if someone can help show me how to make a button to convert text from one language to another using a button? I commonly see this on many sites.

Comment: Please post your exact problem, not demand. Thank you.

Comment: Post what code you have so far. We can help you solve your programming question but we are not here to write the whole solution for you from scratch.

Comment: I always assumed that most sites simply build the multiple language versions of their site and depending on php or javascript... the button toggles the display to the appropriate version.  Google / chrome provide a automatic text translator to your own language, but I wouldn't depend on that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to localize a simple HTML website page in my case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530401/how-to-localize-a-simple-html-website-page-in-my-case)

Comment: There is no special html to convert your site into multiple language variants, the implementation of this is heavily dependent on the platform/programming language you use. If however you are looking for a simple 'plugin' that requires little effort have a look at http://translate.google.com/manager/website/, it offers good translations but is by no means perfect.

Comment: may be you can try google translate, but we could not give you the code, we can only help you solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can have two options of languages separated by different classes and have one of them visible at a time and the button will toggle the language, like this:

```
<script>
    let button = $("button");
    let toggleable = $(".toggleable");
    
    function toggle_lang() {
        toggleable.each(function(index, value) {
            value.text(translate(value.text()));
        });
    };
    button.click(toggle_lang());
</script>
<button type="button">Change Language</button>
<p class="toggleable">Hello</p>
```

Where translate() translates the text that it is given.