# how to implement page translater

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I have developed a site,but now i required to add a language translator in my site. how to add a language translator to translate all content of my site to a desired language dynamically.help me to solve this

Comment: Have a google for 'translation API', there are a lot of services that do this. Don't expect the free ones to be very good though.

Comment: will it work locally...i mean in the absence of network connection,i need such solution @ Rory

Comment: Don't expect the commercial ones to be very good either. If you want to offer content in multiple languages, then get human translators to translate and rewrite your copy.

Comment: You want to dynamically translate your site, on the fly, client side? In a word, no.

Comment: You want it to work locally? In that case you need a dictionary holding translations of every word you want to translate in every language. Short answer, no it's not going to work.

Answer (score 1):

You should not use any translators that do this operation on fly. Remember that translators are your enemy when translating more than one word. Especially when both languages are not english. Secondly this could take many processing resources and without caching it, it will blow up your network.

To do it right, you should apply i18n feature to your site. This will require from you:

- replace any labels on your site with i18n tags with i18n keys
- create i18n property fields holding translations for each i18 key
- change of language will require page reload
- when displaying content (taken from database or the source), you should create content per language, and select it basing on Locale from Request

As you can see, creating fully multi-language app is not a walk in the park, it is hard work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to provide your website content in different languages, you will need a localisation service (depending on the size/scale of your site) or use an API such as [Google Translate's API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs), which is not free. See Beri's answer on performance implications.

You need to do a bit of research yourself and see which solution suits your needs. We don't have much context on your site, so it's a bit difficult to answer.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530401/how-to-localize-a-simple-html-website-page-in-my-case) may be relevant to you.