# Set default language in multi language web site

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a website and I want to support two languages, English and French.

So far, I am using the top solution from this question: [How to localize a simple HTML website page in my case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530401/how-to-localize-a-simple-html-website-page-in-my-case).

HTML

```
  <div>
      <select onchange="select_language(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
      <option value="en">EN</option>
      <option value="fr" selected>FR</option>
    </select>
    <h1 lang="fr"> Nous joindre </h1>
    <h1 lang="en"> Contact Us </h1>
    <p lang="fr"> Pour toutes questions, vous pouvez: </p>
    <p lang="en"> If you have any questions, you can :</p>
  </div>
```

JS

```
function select_language(language) {
    $("[lang]").each(function () {
        if ($(this).attr("lang") == language)
            $(this).show();
        else
            $(this).hide();
    });
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/NBenitus/7ypmo7q1/1/ (in the fiddle, selecting a language in the select field does not change the language. This does work in my web site however.)

My problem is that when the page loads the first time, elements from both languages show by default.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please provide some codes

Comment: Code has been added! :)

Answer (score 0):

You could check the current browser language if possible (via [`window.navigator.language`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/NavigatorLanguage/language) and set it accordingly on `DOMContentLoaded`). A simplified example would look like:

```
(function(window, $) {
    var lang = window.navigator.language;
    if (lang != 'en' || lang != 'fr') {
        lang = 'en'; // assuming en as default language
    }
    // now just set the language accordingly by e.g. setting the proper
    // meta tag or whatever
})(window, jQuery);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am unfortunately quite new to JS, so I am unsure how to apply this to my code. Would you have some hints, please?

Comment: Looking at the page: not really, sry. Imho you should split the content up - completely - by wrapping the dedicated pages in wrapper elements like `<div class="$lang">`. Then you could toggle the language by simply switching a class: `document.body.className = 'en';` and let CSS handle the rest `.fr .fr, .en .en {display: block;} .fr .en, .en .fr {display: none;}`. Good luck.