# How to translate ios cordova long press.

Tags: ios, html, cordova, visual-studio-2013

I am new to HTML5 development and I am building a simple cordova app. In IOS when you click a text and press long press you will see the following options.

- Copy
- Select All
- Define
- Share...

Is there a way to translate this words. 
I changed the language of the phone but the above options are not translating.
Can anyone help me. Thank you.

Comment: your textifled is made in html or native of iOS ?

Comment: HTML and the text is inside the div tags

Comment: see this, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7530401/how-to-localize-a-simple-html-website-page-in-my-case

Answer (score 0):

You can add other languages to your project adding this on the info.plit (with a plugin or a hook)

```
<key>CFBundleLocalizations</key>
<array>
    <string>es</string>
    <string>fr</string>
    <string>...</string>
</array>
```

or if you just support one language, you can just change English here for another language

```
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>English</string>
```

There is an existing plugin to write on the info.plist
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-custom-config

You can use it or use your own plugin that just a config-file tag to add that lines
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/plugin_ref/spec.html#config-file